# Winzip cmd line gives fatal error

Tags: shared-folders, copy, runtime-error, winzip

I'm trying to add folders from a mapped network drive into a zip file using winzip command line but everytime I am receiving this error:

FATAL ERROR: assert failure (WzZipAdd.c@1346)

Please send the file wzCLine.rpt to the address below.

To help solve this problem, please include as detailed as possible a description of what you were doing before the problem occurred, so we can try to reproduce the problem here.

WinZip Computing EMail: support@winzip.com Web: http://www.winzip.com

I sent this file to winzip support team but they said they can't do anything. I don't know why they say that so I'm hoping someone here can help about this.

The mapped network drive is my galaxy s8's internal storage on android 9 pie using the olive tree's webdav app called webdav server (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.webdavserver&hl=en&gl=US).

For example, I added about 100 folders to exclude in a exclude.txt file,
`"\\ipaddress@8080\DavWWWRoot\sdcard\Android\data\org.telegram.messenger\*"` in this type of format, while leaving one folder out of this exclude list to include to zip, I get the above FATAL ERROR: assert failure (WzZipAdd.c@1346)

The syntax I used for winzip command line is:

```
wzzip -a -r -P -yx -e0 -x@"C:\path\to\exclude list.txt" test.zip "\\ipaddress@8080\DavWWWRoot\sdcard\Android\data"
```

Comment: "_I sent this file to winzip support team_" What file(s) did you send to them so they can "_reproduce the problem_"?

Comment: The file named wzCLine.rpt to winzip's support team like several weeks ago got no response from them. Emailed back twice, nothing..

I have disabled my antivirus, tried different folders some of them work some don't work. The syntax I used is

I cd into C:\Program Files\WinZip\ folder then used this syntax

wzzip -a -r -P -yx -e0 test.zip -x@"C:\Users\username\exclude list.txt" "\\ipaddress@8080\DavWWWRoot\sdcard\Android\data"

in the exclude list I have entries to exclude folders in this kind of format
"\\ipaddress@8080\DavWWWRoot\sdcard\path\to\folder\*"

Comment: What made you believe they can use only the wzCLine.rpt file to reproduce the problem ???

Comment: Because thats what it says in the command line "Please send the file wzCLine.rpt to the address below."

Comment: "_tried different folders some of them work some don't work._" I think this is the key. You need to tell them what worked and what didn't work. I am not an IT person. But, I believe I cannot reproduce the problem if I don't have working cases and non-working cases to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Ok so for example in command line, when I add folders to exclude including the problematic folder in Android/data, the same error is reported

So, I'm trying to zip Z:\sdcard\Android\data\org.telegram.messenger and its contents, same error, 

tried with another folder, Z:\sdcard\Android\data\org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service, same error again

basically exclude all others folders except those 2

Comment: Please report what you know so far to their support team.

Comment: I have already emailed them in detail with screenshots at length and the reply I received some weeks ago was "Your issue must be different from what I have encountered. If you want to troubleshoot; along with updating Windows, you should see if your drive has any driver updates. Other than that, I really do not have any help for this."

I sent an email a couple days later and then received no reply except a customer service survey

Comment: You omitted a lot details in your question, how would you expect anyone on this site to help you without knowing these details?

Comment: OK, I will update my question with more details

Comment: I have added additional details to my original question